# how to add text before output field

Tags: php

how i add the text before the output of field ?

the code is :

```
<?php
global $current_user;
echo '<h1>DATI DI FATTURAZIONE</h1>';
echo pmpro_formatAddress(
$current_user->first_name . ' ' . $current_user->last_name,
$current_user->pmpro_baddress1, 
$current_user->pmpro_bcity,
$current_user->pmpro_bstate,
$current_user->pmpro_bzipcode,
$current_user->pmpro_bcountry,
$current_user->pmpro_bphone,
    $current_user->company
);
?>
```

**i would for example :**

name : name lastname

**now is :**

name lastname

thanks everyone

Comment: It might be worth rewriting your question. I for one can't work out what your question is, nor what the example code / output is relevant to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit

```
$current_user->first_name . ' ' . $current_user->last_name,
```

To

```
'Name : '.$current_user->first_name . ' ' . $current_user->last_name,
```